# Simulate taking USB cable in and out

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I have a MacBook at home, where I have a webcam connected to.

The problem is I'm not at home and the surveillance software I'm using can't see it.

Is it possible to simulate taking the USB cable out and putting it back in again?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo kextunload -b "com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI"; sleep 5; sudo kextload -b "com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI"
```

Works on my system, just tested it. I had to run the command 3 times though because for 2 times my usb camera didn't reconnect correctly, no idea why that happened.

Or similar to this with the full path

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
```

Oh well, this work

Comment: It just says it can open CFBundle for /Users/*** /IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext. Can't create IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext. (kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.ExampleBundle not found for unload request.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.ExampleBundle - (libkern/kext) not found.

Comment: Oh sorry.. of course that needs to be removed. See above.

Comment: (kernel) Kext IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext not found for unload request.
Failed to unload IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext - (libkern/kext) not found.

And for the load command IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).

Comment: Ok, then with the full path

Comment: I can see it can find it now. But now it says it cant unload because theres one instances using it

Comment: That's bad news. it works for me. You can try to run "kextstat". In the seconds column, if there is a zero, you can unload the kext directly. If not, note the number of the kext (first column) and grep it by doing e.g. "kextstat | grep 129". The numbers below 129 will be the numbers you have to unload first. Unload them and then the one you want to.